# Why is Google Colab raising an error for reading in a csv and jupyter notebook isn't?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, google-colaboratory

I'm receiving this error when attempting to read in csv data using python and pandas. I don't experience this error in Jupyter notebooks but I'm trying to use google colab and experience the error there. Any ideas why google colab is raising the error but jupyter isn't?

```
df = pd.read_csv('./final_data_for_modeling.csv')

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ParserError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-3a755ce18082> in <module>()
      2 
      3 # Load the dataset into a pandas dataframe.
----> 4 df = pd.read_csv('./final_data_for_modeling.csv')


ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 3, saw 2
```

For contrast here is a screenshot of the success in jupyter

[image: Screenshot of the success in jupyter]

If you'd like to take a look at the csv here is a dropbox link to the data:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/i3od76b52t19vzr/final_data_for_modeling.csv?dl=0

Comment: It could probably be answered is only you had shown the content of the csv file **as text**. Currently we can only try to guess...

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors.

Comment: We need a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works out of the box for me. Here's a complete notebook:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1CATW8DtNh9wZTKpp5bV2DqfU6ChkFgty

Full code & output:
[image]